# Big query data transfer

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer-process

I am trying to use GoogleDataTransfer to import the DFP data to BQ. When I create  the transfer method I get an error without any details:

> Error in creating a new transfer

Does anyone know why I get the error message? I use the correct Network ID.

[image]

Comment: I'm an engineer working on the BQ Data Transfer - sorry that the error message is so useless here!
Not sure what is causing this - do you maybe have an adblocker? Or not the right permissions on the project? The 'add' button should be opening an OAuth dialog. In chrome (and other browsers are similar), you can open the Debug Console (on Linux/Windows, press F12). Then, reproduce the issue - the console should indicate what is happening.

Comment: @Tib51 I'm also getting this - after the OAuth popup